# Encryption algorithm/library for .NET 2.0 + C++

Tags: c++, encryption, .net-2.0, aes, rijndael

I need a standard, Microsoft delivered, encryption library that works for both .NET 2.0 and C++. What would you suggest?

We find that AES is only offered in .NET 3.5 (and available in C++)

We find that Rijndael is used in .NET 2.0 but not available in the standard C++ libraries.

If I am wrong (very good chance), can you point me in the right direction?

Worst case scenario, I suppose I can call the Rijndael algorithm from .NET using PInvoke but I would rather have a native solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We successfully do a similar thing that I hope might help you:

#### C++ CryptoAPI

- [CryptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380239(VS.85).aspx) is pure Win32 (c/c++), native to all Microsoft OS's.
- Use [Enhanced Cryptographic Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386986(VS.85).aspx) (`MS_ENHANCED_PROV`)
- Use [Triple DES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382020(VS.85).aspx) (`CALG_3DES`) algorithm

#### .NET TripleDes Provider

- Use [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(VS.80).aspx) on the .NET side.

#### Side Notes

- We **avoid CAPICOM** like the plague as the deployment nightmares that come with it are not worth the hassle.
- Byte order on the .NET side can come into play at times. For example, to consume a key that is generated on the C++ (CryptoAPI)  side, you need to reverse the byte array prior to using it within the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.

If you would like more details please leave a comment and I can give more. Happy crypto!

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this... and of course, any other information you could provide, I would be delighted.

Comment: don't forget the AES Crypto Provider - also available as part of Windows.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386979(VS.85).aspx  It delivers AES algorithms, which is what the OP wanted I think.

Comment: True, but it's worth noting that AES algorithms are not supported on Windows 2000/NT.

Answer (score 3):

AES and Rijndael are essentially the same algorithm with a restriction on block size and cipher mode. So as long as you can live with the [restrictions](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/The-Differences-Between-Rijndael-and-AES.aspx) (which are not onerous) you can use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

3DES is available via Capicom.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382010(VS.85).aspx) for info.

Answer (score 0):

Windows includes a C/C++ AES encryption library, as part of the [AES Cryptographic Services Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386979(VS.85).aspx).   It is suitable for use from within native C/C++ applications.